# React component "html" changes are not displayed

Tags: reactjs, components, react-component

I'm working on someone else example code and I made some changes for the sake of testing.
One thing I stumbled upon was that I made some minimal changes on the html part of a component and the changes are not beeing displayed.

```
import React from 'react'

const Choices = ({ handleNewActivity, handleAddActivity, name }) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <button id="primary-btn" onClick={() => handleNewActivity()}>Noooooo thanks...</button>
      <button id="success-btn" onClick={() => handleAddActivity(name)}>Sounds fun!</button>
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default Choices
```

Like in this component I changed the phrase "No thanks..." to "Noooooo thanks..."
and the app continues to display as "No thanks..."

[image of component rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MO47e.png)

Maybe you guys can help me figure it out why this is happening.

If anyone would like to take a look at the code you can find it on:
https://github.com/mondadori89/deploying-fullstack-with-heroku-sample

Comment: Have you tried stopping the process and starting again? Some times applications aren't setup to automatically reload.

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes, I did tried many things like restart the process, even deploy the app on heroku hoping it was a local problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const handleAddActivity = newActivity => {
    activityService
      .addActivity({
        activity: newActivity,
      })
      .then(() => {
        setActivities([...activities, {activity: newActivity}])
      })
    activityService
      .getNewActivity()
      .then(data => {
        setNewActivity(data.activity)
      })
  }
```

This is your `handleAddActivity`.

it is required a parameter `newActivity`. but you are not using on `Noooooo thanks...` button

```
<button id="primary-btn" onClick={() => handleNewActivity()}>Noooooo thanks...</button>
```

Please add a parameter or make another activity to handle the `Nooooo thanks ...` event.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response,
The functions are working acctualy, the app is working fine, it is just the html part of the components (all of them, not just this one) that do not change, like I changed "No, thanks" to "Noooooo thanks..." and it didn't change. Probably I'm doing something wrong with commit versions. I will investigate more.